# How to get data frame from stargazer list

Tags: r, list, stargazer

I would like to get a dataframe for each list item from a list object. Below is an example

```
mtcars_sumstat <- mtcars %>% 
select(mpg:qsec,am) %>% 
as.data.frame() %>% 
split(.$am) %>% 
 walk(~stargazer(.,type = "text",
             summary.stat = c ("n", "mean", "sd")))

mtcars_sumstat

=============================
Statistic N   Mean   St. Dev.
-----------------------------
mpg       19 17.147   3.834  
cyl       19  6.947   1.545  
disp      19 290.379 110.172 
hp        19 160.263  53.908 
drat      19  3.286   0.392  
wt        19  3.769   0.777  
qsec      19 18.183   1.751  
am        19  0.000   0.000  
-----------------------------

=============================
Statistic N   Mean   St. Dev.
-----------------------------
mpg       13 24.392   6.167  
cyl       13  5.077   1.553  
disp      13 143.531  87.204 
hp        13 126.846  84.062 
drat      13  4.050   0.364  
wt        13  2.411   0.617  
qsec      13 17.360   1.792  
am        13  1.000   0.000  
-----------------------------
```

When I run the following code, I get two data frames for 2 list items; But, those dataframes contain  the actual data, not the above summary statistics.

```
list2env(mtcars_sumstat,.GlobalEnv)
```

Basically, I want the above summary statistics in two separate data frames as data frame OBJECT in "GLOBAL ENVIRONMENT". Is there any way I can do this? The data frame should look like this as an data frame OBJECT -

```
Statistic N   Mean   St. Dev.
mpg       13 24.392   6.167  
cyl       13  5.077   1.553  
disp      13 143.531  87.204 
hp        13 126.846  84.062 
drat      13  4.050   0.364  
wt        13  2.411   0.617  
qsec      13 17.360   1.792  
am        13  1.000   0.000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update** Per OP comments

It may be easier to just use standard `dplyr` manipulation to get summary statistics.  Use `pivot_longer`, `group_by`, and `summarise`:

```r
mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg:qsec, am) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-am) %>%
  group_by(am, name) %>%
  summarise(across(value, .fns=list(mean = mean, sd = sd, n = length), .names = "{fn}")) %>%
  group_split()
```

Output:

```r
$`0`
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   am [1]
     am name    mean      sd     n
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>   <dbl> <int>
1     0 cyl     6.95   1.54     19
2     0 disp  290.   110.       19
3     0 drat    3.29   0.392    19
4     0 hp    160.    53.9      19
5     0 mpg    17.1    3.83     19
6     0 qsec   18.2    1.75     19
7     0 wt      3.77   0.777    19

$`1`
# A tibble: 7 x 5
# Groups:   am [1]
     am name    mean     sd     n
  <dbl> <chr>  <dbl>  <dbl> <int>
1     1 cyl     5.08  1.55     13
2     1 disp  144.   87.2      13
3     1 drat    4.05  0.364    13
4     1 hp    127.   84.1      13
5     1 mpg    24.4   6.17     13
6     1 qsec   17.4   1.79     13
7     1 wt      2.41  0.617    13
```

**Previous answer**

Change `walk` to `map`, and add `map(tibble)`:

```r
mtcars_sumstat <- mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg:qsec,am) %>% 
  as.data.frame() %>% 
  split(.$am) %>% 
  map_df(~stargazer(.,type = "text", summary.stat = c ("n", "mean", "sd"))) %>%
  map(tibble)
```

Output:

```r
mtcars_sumstat
$`0`
# A tibble: 13 x 1
   `<chr>`                        
   <chr>                          
 1 ""                             
 2 "============================="
 3 "Statistic N   Mean   St. Dev."
 4 "-----------------------------"
 5 "mpg       19 17.147   3.834  "
 6 "cyl       19  6.947   1.545  "
 7 "disp      19 290.379 110.172 "
 8 "hp        19 160.263  53.908 "
 9 "drat      19  3.286   0.392  "
10 "wt        19  3.769   0.777  "
11 "qsec      19 18.183   1.751  "
12 "am        19  0.000   0.000  "
13 "-----------------------------"

$`1`
# A tibble: 13 x 1
   `<chr>`                        
   <chr>                          
 1 ""                             
 2 "============================="
 3 "Statistic N   Mean   St. Dev."
 4 "-----------------------------"
 5 "mpg       13 24.392   6.167  "
 6 "cyl       13  5.077   1.553  "
 7 "disp      13 143.531  87.204 "
 8 "hp        13 126.846  84.062 "
 9 "drat      13  4.050   0.364  "
10 "wt        13  2.411   0.617  "
11 "qsec      13 17.360   1.792  "
12 "am        13  1.000   0.000  "
13 "-----------------------------"
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you have idea how can clear the " " signs and create a nice data frame.

Comment: Can you edit your post to provide expected output?  I'm not sure what "nice data frame" means.

Comment: If you actually want the summary statistics in separate numeric columns, it'd be much easier to generate them using normal `dplyr` methods.  Stargazer is really for formatting output, not for data manipulation.

Comment: I am actually trying to work on rmarkdown (latex) pdf for my research output, but do not know how `dplyr` can help me for that purpose.

Comment: Ok, see updated answer for a much quicker solution that does not rely on `stargazer`.

Comment: Thanks. When I try to create 2 dataframe from 2 list items using `list2env(mtcars_sumstat,.GlobalEnv)` from your updated code, it shows the following error message `Error in list2env(sumstat_mtcars, .GlobalEnv) : 
  names(x) must be a character vector of the same length as x`

Comment: Your stated goal is: "Basically, I want the above summary statistics in two separate data frame. Is there any way I can do this?"  This answer demonstrates two different ways to do that.  I don't know why you need `list2env`, but if you actually need an answer to a different question than the one you have asked, please either open a new question, or update your post to make the constraints of your problem more clear.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I have updated my question.